# A better way of finding out if any running process was launched from a given file?

Tags: c#

I have to check whether another process is running, based only on the name of the EXE file.

Currently I get the process list and then query the `MainModule.FileName` property, however some processes throw `Win32Exception` "Unable to enumerate the process modules" when you access the `MainModule` property.
Currently I am filtering to a 'safe list' by catching these access exceptions thus:

```
List<Process> processes = new List<Process>(Process.GetProcesses());

// Slow, but failsafe.  As we are dealing with core system
// data which we cannot filter easily, we have to use the absense of
// exceptions as a logic flow control.
List<Process> safeProcesses = new List<Process>();
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessModule pm = p.MainModule;
        // Some system processes (like System and Idle)
        // will throw an exception when accessing the main module.
        // So if we got this far, we can add to the safe list
        safeProcesses.Add(p);
    }
    catch { } // Exception for logic flow only.
}
```

Needless to say I really don't like having to use exceptions like this.

Is there a better way to get the process list for which I can access the `MainModule` property, or even a better method of checking if any process was spawned from a given file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that there are only System and Idle processes that will throw the exception so you can filter them out before and you're ready to go.

Comment: YEs, as mentionned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.modules.aspx 
when accessing the `Modules` property of a `Process`, a Win32Exception will be thrown when :
You are attempting to access the Modules property for either the system process or the idle process. These processes do not have modules.

Comment: Thank you - my first version did just that, but I wasn't sure if there would be any others (I must have missed that sentence in the MSDN library, because I read that whole page twice!).

Answer (score 0):

I will use like

```
        List<Process> processes = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
        List<Process> safeProcesses  = processes .Select(X => 
        {
            try {  ProcessModule  pp = X.MainModule; return X; }

            catch { return null; }
        }).Where(X=>X!=null).ToList();
```

Comment: Pretty much the same technique (catching exceptions) but wrapped in Linq instead of a foreach loop.  I'm really looking for a way to do this without using exceptions.

Comment: Actually, I've given you a +1 for the comment, because it's useful to know how to do this in linq, but it's not quite the answer I'm looking for (I don't want to use exceptions).